# ansible module postgresql_schema not supporting taken backup and restore for single schema from database

Tags: ansible, postgresql-9.4

I have tried to backup and restore single schema from the Postgres database but getting below error, using below yml file
I have used module postgresql_db also, but getting error.

```
fatal: [192.168.1.18]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (postgresql_schema) module: target Supported parameters include: ca_cert, cascade_drop, database, login_host, login_password, login_unix_socket, login_user, owner, port, schema, session_role, ssl_mode, state"}

---

- hosts: dbserver
  become: true
  gather_facts: yes

  vars:
    dbname: dbname
    dbuser: dbuser
    password: dbpassword

  tasks:
  - name: Schema backup
    postgresql_schema:
      name: dbname
      schema: schema1
      state: dump
      target: /tmp/schema.sql.gz
      login_user: "{{ dbuser }}"
      login_password: "{{ password }}"
```

Comment: This boils down to `Unsupported parameters for (postgresql_schema) module: target`. And as one would expect [the module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/postgresql_schema_module.html) does not reference any `target` parameter for this module.

Comment: yaa but need to save the file, how to do that?

Comment: Obviously not with this module which does not have a `dump` state either => `postgresql_schema – Add or remove PostgreSQL schema`

Answer (score 0):

I Have used the postgresql_db module for single schema backup and working fine, public is schema name.

```
- name: Dump a single schema for an existing database
  postgresql_db:
    name: acme
    state: dump
    target: /tmp/acme.sql
    target_opts: "-n public"
```